# Отделение музыки от голоса

Tags: python, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-речи

На python написал голосового ассистента, которого внедрил в колонку. В нём есть функция включении музыки, однако, когда воспроизводится музыка, голос просто не слышно из за громкости аудио.

Проблему пытался решить использованием двух микрофонов (один сверху другой снизу), но это не помогает.

Есть ли какой то вариант решения этой проблемы на программном уровне? Например при помощи нейросетей отделять музыку от моего голоса? Поиск в интернете не помог.

Использую speech_recognition в связке с speechkit от yandex cloud.

Кусочек кода с распознанием:

```
def listen():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Ожидаю команды: ")
            r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            r.dynamic_energy_adjustment_damping = 1
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print(1)
            with open("output.wav", "wb") as f:
                f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
            clip = AudioFileClip("output.wav")
            # print("Начинаю экспорт файла...")
            clip.write_audiofile("output.ogg")
            # print("Экспорт файла завершен.")
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + iam,
            }
            params = (
                ('folderId', '*****************'),
                ('lang', 'ru-RU'),
            )
            with open("output.ogg", "rb") as f:
                # print(1)
                start = time.time()
                response = requests.post('https://stt.api.cloud.yandex.net/speech/v1/stt:recognize', headers=headers,
                                         params=params, data=f)
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    print(response.text)
                    print(response.status_code)
                    return "Ошибка в распознавании"
                # print(response.json()['result'])
                stop = time.time()
                all_time = float(stop)-float(start)
                text_answer = remove_duplicates(response.json()['result']).lower()
                print(f'Распознано {text_answer} за {all_time} сек.')
                return text_answer
```

Comment: В принципе есть какие-то сетки, выделяющие отдельно из песен музыку и голос, но вообще это, мягко говоря, сложная задача. Диапазон частот у них пересекается. На примитивном уровне можно попробовать вырезать из сигнала диапазон частот, на котором скорее всего будет голос, а не музыка. Возможно, для распознавания команд этого и достаточно будет, даже если там фоном какие-то обрезки музыки будут, надо пробовать.